# mongoexport using subprocess failed

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, subprocess

I have been trying to export a csv from mongodb, using Python's subprocess module. However, the **spacing in my file path** is hindering me from exporting correctly.

This works in Windows cmd if the input/output are where the script lies. So, there is no need to specify the path.

```
mongoexport --db wsg-database --collection wsg --type=csv --fieldFile fields.txt --out export.csv
```

If I specify the path like this below, it gives a syntax error:

```
subprocess.call("mongoexport --db test-database --collection wsg --type=csv --fieldFile "C:\Users\Jess Teo\Desktop\fields.txt" --out "C:\Users\Jess Teo\Desktop\export.csv"", shell=True)
```

Using a list form of the subprocess gives out an empty file.

```
subprocess.call(["mongoexport", "--db", "test-database", "--collection", \
                 "wsg", "--type=csv", "--fieldFile", \
                 "C:\Users\Jess Teo\Desktop\fields.txt",\
                 "--out", "C:\Users\Jess Teo\Desktop\export.csv"])
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You get a syntax error because you forgot to quote and escape the quotes around the output filename, and fields file as well ( since your directory path has a space in it). You got no output in the second attempt for much the same reasons. IMHO you should always use *nix direction for slashes in paths. And some abstraction of paths in general.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn, would u be able to type a corrected sample out so that I can understand clearer on what u meant?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, my colleague has advised a simple resolution. Just add an "r" at the beginning of the command, with the double quotes around the file path and it will work.

```
subprocess.call(r'mongoexport --db test-database --collection wsg --type=csv --fieldFile "C:\Users\Jess Teo\Desktop\fields.txt" --out "C:\Users\Jess Teo\Desktop\export.csv"', shell=True)
```